# How to handle browser cache downloaded from cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using `AWS Cloudfront` to distribute content. The origin is a s3 bucket. I can manage each file expire date on `cloudfront` by setting a matedata `Cache-Control` on the file in s3. For example, if I set `max-age=1000` in `Cache-Control`, cloudfront will cache the file for 1000 seconds. But the files can also be cached by users' browser. How can I control how long the files cached in users' browser?

Answer (score 0):

`Cache-Control max-age` is transferred to the client's browser too.

So if you set `Cache-Control max-age=1000` it means it will be cached in Cloudfront for the amount of 1000 seconds. The same applies for client's browser - it will be cached there for 1000 seconds as well.

If you would like to set different values for client's browser and Cloudfront use `Cache-Control s-maxage` for the Cloudfront. This value is accepted by Cloudfront, but ignored by client's browser. For the client browser stay with `Cache-Control max-age=1000`.

So if you set, for example, `Cache-Control s-maxage=2000` and `Cache-Control max-age=1000` it means it will be cached for 2000 seconds in the Cloudfront and 1000 seconds in client's browser.